# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Framework ReactJS and am trying to make two different gets on one page. Each get receives a different array of different databases.
Can you help me understand this mistake, please?

[image: Error_slice]

```
class Example extends React.Component{

constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.props.dispatch (get1({email:this.props.email}),get2({email:this.props.email}));
      this.options = {
      onPageChange: this.onPageChange.bind(this),
      onSizePerPageList: this.sizePerPageListChange.bind(this)
      };
}

sizePerPageListChange(sizePerPage) {
    alert(`sizePerPage: ${sizePerPage}`);
  }

  onPageChange(page, sizePerPage) {
    alert(`page: ${page}, sizePerPage: ${sizePerPage}`);
}

componentDidMount() {
          setTimeout(() => {
                this.refs.table2.forceUpdate();
                this.refs.table3.forceUpdate();
          }, 500);
}


  render() {


    return (


<table width={1000} height={500}>
<tr>
  <td>
      <BootstrapTable ref="table2" data={ this.props.array_1 }
          options={ this.options } multiColumnSort={ 2 } striped hover>
                    <td dataField='att_1' isKey={true} width="55px">Col_1</td>
                    <td dataField='att_2' width="140px">Col_1</td>
                    <td dataField='att_3' width="140px">Col_2</td>
                    <td dataField='att_4' width="30px">Col_3</td>
      </BootstrapTable>
  </td>
  <td width={50}> </td>
  <td>
      <BootstrapTable ref="table3" data={ this.props.array_2 }
          options={ this.options } multiColumnSort={ 2 } striped hover>
                    <td dataField='att_5' isKey={true} width="55px">Col_4</td>
                    <td dataField='att_6' width="140px">Col_5</td>
                    <td dataField='att_7' width="30px">Col_6</td>
      </BootstrapTable>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>


    );
  }
};


function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    array_1: state.proj.array_1,
    array_2: state.hist.array_2,
    email: state.email
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,{get1,get2})(Example);
```

Comment: It seems that `this.props.array_1` (and possibly `this.props.array_2`) are not defined. Are you sending them as props to your component? If your "gets" are http GETs then perhaps you need to wait for a response before trying to render your component. Does that make sense? You may be rendering it before you have the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

perfaps this link will help it has the same issue: 
[link](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/1053)

i think is the problem with passing an empty object to the data of bootstrapTable since it only accepts array.
you should check if you